# xdotool and xbindkeys

Tags: xbindkeys, xdotool

I have an Acrobat reader that does not zoom on Control+plus but rather on Control+acute (Control-plus annoyingly rotates the document).

I would like to fix this using xbindkeys and xdotool but the complication is that Control-plus is also used by other applications.

So the idea is to intercept Control-plus, check if Acrobat is the active window. If so send Acrobat a Control-acute, otherwise send the Control-plus.

Here my current attempt for the script that xbindkeys starts on Control+plus:

```
WM_CLASS=$(xprop -id `xdotool getactivewindow` WM_CLASS |awk '{print $4}')

if [ "$WM_CLASS" = "\"Acroread"\" ];
then
   sleep 0.1s;
   xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+acute
else
   killall xbindkeys
   xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+plus
   xbindkeys
fi
```

This actually works but the problem is that if I would not kill xbindkeys than xdotool sending ctrl-plus would again trigger xbindkeys and so on.

But of course this means that every time I hit Control+plus in a non-acrobat window xbindkeys needs to be killed and restarted...

Is there a better way to do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Unrelated crystal ball: you have a german-language keyboard and acroread thinks the layout is U.S., is that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

Based [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/98355/302085) on Ask Ubuntu, it would appear that killing and then restarting xbindkeys is not necessary.

Comment: If that AU link becomes deleted, would you please import the relevant bits here? Thank you!